# SwiftUI Image flashes during animation

Tags: ios, swift, image, animation, swiftui

I'm experiencing a confusing issue in SwiftUI where Images on a simple VStack card flash during interaction. See the video below:

[Short video demonstrating the problem](https://imgur.com/FXHXFNf)

I've split this out from the app I'm working on into a simpler sample project. Essentially, there's a simple button that loads the PhotoPicker and adds photos to state. Each photo card uses an `ObservableObject` to track whether it is selected--this gets toggled on tap to ensure only a single card is selected at a time.

```
class EntriesState : ObservableObject {
    @Published var selectedIndex : Int? = nil
}

struct PhotoView : View {
    var image : Data;
    var index : Int;
    @ObservedObject var entriesState: EntriesState
    
    
    var body: some View {
                        VStack {
                            if let uiImage = UIImage(data: image) {
                                Image(uiImage: uiImage)
                                    .resizable()
                                    .scaledToFit()
                                    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 24.0))
                                    .onAppear() {
                                        print("Image \(index) appeared")
                                    }
                            }
                            if entriesState.selectedIndex == index {
                                Text("This is the description for the image")
                            }
                        }
                        .padding(20)
                        .background(Color.blue)
                        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 24.0))
                        .onTapGesture {
                            // Removing `withAnimation` fixes the flashing,
                            // but removes the animation.
                            
                            // Is there a way to have the nice animation
                            // as the card expands, without the image flashing?
                            withAnimation {
                                if entriesState.selectedIndex == index {
                                    entriesState.selectedIndex = nil
                                } else {
                                    entriesState.selectedIndex = index
                                }
                            }
                        }
        
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selectedItems = [PhotosPickerItem]()
    @State private var selectedImages = [Data]()
    @StateObject var entriesState = EntriesState()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ScrollView {
                LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 200))]) {
                    ForEach(0..<selectedImages.count, id: \.self) { i in
                        PhotoView(image: selectedImages[i], index: i, entriesState: entriesState)
                            .padding(20)
                    }
                }
            }
            .toolbar {
                PhotosPicker("Select images", selection: $selectedItems, matching: .images)
            }
            .onChange(of: selectedItems) {
                Task {
                    selectedImages.removeAll()

                    for item in selectedItems {
                        if let data = try? await item.loadTransferable(type: Data.self) {
                            selectedImages.append(data)
                           
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried:

1. Using @Binding instead of @ObservableObject to track the selected index.
2. Adding `.id(index)` to the image
3. Tracking `.onAppear` calls for the image--I'm only seeing that called once, not multiple times like I would expect if the image were being rerendered.
4. Removing the animation. This fixes the problem, but I'd like to be able to animate the growing/shrinking of the card
5. Using `@State var selected` in the `PhotoView`. This prevents the flashing on ALL images, but the image still flashes on the selected card. See [here](https://imgur.com/arIoMwQ)
6. Searching StackOverflow and Google for solutions. Notably, I've found people with similar problems [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/SwiftUI/comments/103d478/image_flashing_during_animation/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60346009/swiftui-list-remote-image-loading-images-flickering-reloading) but nothing suggested has worked :(

Please let me know if you have any suggestions or questions! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution! [Here](https://imgur.com/Ok3M1d0) is a video of what it looks like now.

The solution is pretty simple--instead of storing the image data in the view, store the UIImage directly. My guess is the flash comes from converting the Data -> UIImage during the animation as for a frame or two there might be nothing to show.

```
import SwiftUI
import PhotosUI

class EntriesState : ObservableObject {
    @Published var selectedIndex : Int? = nil
}

struct PhotoView : View {
    var image : Data
    var index : Int
    @ObservedObject var entriesState: EntriesState
    
    var uiImage : UIImage? = nil // Use the UIImage itself
    
    init(image: Data, index: Int, entriesState: EntriesState) {
        self.image = image
        self.index = index
        self.entriesState = entriesState

        // Convert the image data into a UIImage, store it in the view
        if let uiImage = UIImage(data: image) {
            self.uiImage = uiImage
        }
    }
    
    
    var body: some View {
                        VStack {
                            if let uiImage = self.uiImage{
                        Image(uiImage: uiImage)
                                        .resizable()
                                        .scaledToFit()
                                        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 24.0))
                                        .id(index)
                                        .onAppear() {
                                            print("Image \(index) appeared")
                                        }
                            }
                            if entriesState.selectedIndex == index {
                                Text("This is the description for the image")
                            }
                        }
                        .padding(20)
                        .background(Color.red)
                        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 24.0))
                        .onTapGesture {
                            withAnimation {
                                entriesState.selectedIndex = entriesState.selectedIndex == index ? nil : index
                            }
                        }
        
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selectedItems = [PhotosPickerItem]()
    @State private var selectedImages = [Data]()
    @State private var entriesState = EntriesState()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ScrollView {
                LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 200))]) {
                    ForEach(0..<selectedImages.count, id: \.self) { i in
                        PhotoView(image: selectedImages[i], index: i, entriesState: entriesState)

                            .padding(20)
                    }
                }
            }
            .toolbar {
                PhotosPicker("Select images", selection: $selectedItems, matching: .images)
            }
            .onChange(of: selectedItems) { _ in
                Task {
                    selectedImages.removeAll()

                    for item in selectedItems {
                        if let data = try? await item.loadTransferable(type: Data.self) {
                            selectedImages.append(data)
                           
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you already tried `.onAppear()` method but, my best guess is that the flashing happens because of the `.resizable()` modifier being applied to the `Image` view. As we know, this modifier recalculates the size of the image based on the new layout constraints **during the animation**. *That may be* the reason you're facing this issue. In order to handle this, `.onAppear()` can be used. Among other things.

I've looked through the links you provided and came up with solution, hope that works out for you.

We can introduce a **separate state** variable to track the selected state of each `PhotoView` and we can avoid modifying the `entriesState.selectedIndex` directly during the animation. This separation *should* prevent the recalculation of the `Image` view's size and as a result, prevents the flash effect.

```swift
struct PhotoView : View {
    var image : Data;
    var index : Int;
    @ObservedObject var entriesState: EntriesState
    @State private var selected: Bool = false // here is our new state

    // rest of your code here
}
```

Now let's modify the `.onAppear()` in the `Image` view to set the initial value of `selected` based on the `selectedIndex`.

```swift
.onAppear() {
    selected = entriesState.selectedIndex == index
}
```

After that, we can update the `onTapGesture` to toggle the `selected` state instead of directly modifying `entriesState.selectedIndex`.

```swift
.onTapGesture {
    withAnimation { // also using withAnimation, ive seen it from the reddit post
        selected.toggle()
    }
}
```

Finally, update the if condition in the `VStack` to use the `selected` state.

```swift
if isSelected {
    Text("This is the description for the image")
}
```

With these changes, the image should animate smoothly without any flashes when tapped. Hope that solutions works for you.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Sadly, that did not fix the flashing issue. I'm guessing it's because `onAppear` is only called a single time for each `PhotoView` rather than on each tap. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I see that you found the solution already! Im so glad, hope I could've helped a little but no luck on that lol

Answer (score 0):

I just a similar problem to this when in my app in which you can compare a few selected photos. Even though I applied the accepted solution I still had the flicker thing because the individual views were recreated on each gesture.

I solved this by creating a new model for those images that are selected for comparison and load the UIImage inside the init of the model. By doing this, the image is always initialized because the model is the same across all renders.

The following is the new model that holds.

```
class ComparableDayRecord {
    var date: String
    var weight: String
    var image: UIImage
    
    init(date: String, weight: String, image: Data) {
        self.date = date
        self.weight = weight
        self.image = UIImage(data: image)!
    }
    
    public static func make(record: DayRecord) -> ComparableDayRecord {
        return ComparableDayRecord(date: record.dateFormatted, weight: record.weightInKgsFormatted, image: record.photo!)
    }
}
```